# Why does ide say "Value captured in a closure" when using Iterable.flatMap but doesn't when using map then flatten in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
inline fun <T : Any, E : Any> batchQuery(
    paramsToBeChunked: Collection<T>,
    batchSize: Int = 500,
    crossinline queryAction: (params: Collection<T>) -> List<E>
) = paramsToBeChunked.chunked(batchSize).flatMap { queryAction(it) }
```

[image]

```
inline fun <T : Any, E : Any> batchQuery(
    paramsToBeChunked: Collection<T>,
    batchSize: Int = 500,
    crossinline queryAction: (params: Collection<T>) -> List<E>
) = paramsToBeChunked.chunked(batchSize).map { queryAction(it) }.flatten()
```

[image]

Is there any potential problem when using flatMap?

IMHO, map, flatten, flatMap are all inline functions, so these two implementations are equivalent, is this right?

Comment: what do you mean by 'ide say', is this an error or warning, how exactly is this being reported, please be clear

Comment: @mightyWOZ thanks for reminding me, i added some screenshots, i'm not sure it is a warning or not..

Comment: I doubt there is any problem with it. Note this is not a warning, but just information about the variable. I believe both of these solutions inline everything in exactly the same way. We can even check that the resulting bytecode of both the function itself and function that invokes it is almost identical. Why does it say that the variable is captured? This is a mystery ;-) Anyway, you can replace it with `flatMap(queryAction)` and stop thinking about it. No closure - no problem :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fun wasn't `inline` then in both cases `queryAction` would have to be captured in a closure, because it's coming from outside of the lambda. It means that a class which is generated under the hood holds a reference to the variable, and when the lambda is eventually executed, it uses that reference.

But here, it's inlined just fine. Idea tries it's best to give information about captured variables but in this situation it might be a limitation of Idea's static analysis. The first message is just incorrect.

As @broot suggested, you can replace `.map { f(it) }` with just `.map(f)`.